# Bootstrap image spacing

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I use bootstrap v4 alpha 6 and I trying to have images with opacity and font awesome icon on them. It works great until I resize it on medium screen.
At that point I get some spacing between my images[image]

Comment: Change the image width from `max-width:100%` to `width:100%`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the image width from `max-width:100%` to `width:100%`